# Using a variable to call a dataframe in another pythonfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to figure out a way to call a dataframe in a different python script using a variable.

I have a main dataframe (maindf) in main.py that holds the names of all the "sub" dataframes (called df1, df2....df9) located in other.py
other.py is imported properly using `import others` ive also used `from others import df1`.

Variable gets created by looping through the main dataframe to get the correct name of one of the sub dataframes using `dfname = (maindf.loc[i, ['dfnames']].values[0])`.

What I'm currently doing to access the correct dataframe after the variable is created by using if statements and it makes me wanna vomit just looking at it.

```
if dfname == "df1":
    df = others.df1
if dfname == "df2":
    df = others.df2
if dfname == "df3":
    df = others.df4
print(df)
```

except with many more of these if statements. gets me the result i want but theres gotta be a better way to go about it.
my original idea was to do this.

```
df = others.dfname
print(df)
```

I also tried moving the dataframes df1-df9 into main.py but still cant call them using a variable.

Comment: ANY TIME you find yourself writing `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, etc., you need to replace that with a list or a dictionary, either of which would solve this problem nicely.

Comment: i am a little confused by what you mean exactly. the variables df1,df2,df3.... are stored in maindf which is what i use to access them. is that what youre saying i should be doing or something else? thanks for the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly agree with @TimRoberts, **use a container**. Dictionaries are perfect for this case as you could do `other.dict_container['df1']`.

That said you can access the attribute by name with `getattr`: `getattr(other, 'df1')`

Comment: the getattr worked perfectly for what i wanted.  i used `df = getattr(other, dfname)` much appreciated!